# How to save model that belongs to more than one model without loosing laravel convention?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this convention issue/question as a laravel beginner

Here is one example of table structure

```
parents
    id - integer
    name - string

therapists
   id - integer
   name- integer

kid
   id - integer
   name - string
   parent_id - integer
   therapist_id - integer
```

Now, parents and therapists hasMany kids and
kid belongsTo parents and therapists

Here are model examples:

```
class Parent extends Model {

    public function kids()
    {
        return $this->HasMany('Kid');
    }

 }

 class Therapist extends Model {

    public function kids()
    {
       return $this->HasMany('Kid');
    }

  }

  class Kid extends Model {

     public function parents()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('Parent');
     }


     public function therapists()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('Therapist');
     }

  }
```

So, now my question..
How would I save a new Kid Model in database?

```
 $parent = Parent::find(1);
 $therapist = Therapist::find(1);

 $kid = new Kid;
 $kid->therapist_id = $therapist->id;

 $parent->kids()->save($kid);
```

Or maybe trough therapist Model?

```
 $therapist = Therapist::find(1);
 $parent = Parent::find(1);


 $kid = new Kid;
 $kid->parent_id = $parent->id;

 $therapist->kids()->save($kid);
```

Or there is another convention, or maybe I'm not getting this right?
So far I can see, this has nothing to do with polymorphic relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those work. I personally like this the most:

```
$therapist = Therapist::find(1);
$parent = Parent::find(1);

$kid = new Kid;
$kid->parents()->associate($parent);
$kid->therapists()->associate($therapist);
$kid->save();
```

Also I suggest you rename your relations on `Kid` to `parent()` and `therapist()` since a it can just belong to *one* parent or therapist.